# How to apply star rating when using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

i want to use star rating to show vendor rating and quality of product based on user feedback. But i don't how to apply star rating? I am using angular material

```html
<star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" rating ="3" >
</star-rating-comp>
```

this work for me but i don't know how to pick rating(number of stars) selected by user

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ask], as your question is not currently answerable by [so] standards.

Comment: <star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" rating ="3" ></star-rating-comp>  this work for me but i don't know how to pick rating(number of stars) selected by user

Comment: Now i think this code should be enough to give answer or you need more explanation @Anderi Gheorghui

Comment: Your **question** needs to contain enough code to define the problem, what you have tried and the research you have performed. If any of the above is `null`, most times community response is negative and the question is considered of poor quality. Ideally your question should contain a [mcve]. Don't use comments to clarify the question. Update the question instead. As of now, it is impossible to determine: what angular version you're using, what star rating plugin you are using (there's no star rating in angular core).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [angular-star-rating](https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-star-rating). According to [documentation](https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-star-rating/wiki/Property-bindings#control-modifier), you should use `rating` to set the rating:

```
<star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" [rating]="3"></star-rating-comp>
```

See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-star-rating-demo-dakkwc?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: This works fine but apparently this project is not being actively maintained. Some has experienced issues while upgrading to Angular 8